# Issue with resubmitting the form after validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn Spring MVC with small application but got stuck with an issue.

I have created a form for user registration, now on form submission I am doing validation using annotations.

When the validation fails, I am re-displaying the form with error details. But when I re-submit the form, I am facing issue with how to handle the URL mapping.

Here is my controller code:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService personService;

    public PersonService getPersonService() {
        return personService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/allpersons")
    public String showPersonListPage(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("persons", getPersonService().fetchAllPersons());
        return "person_list";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = GET)
    public String showNewPersonForm(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("person", new Person());
        return "new_person";
    } 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPersonFromForm(@Valid Person person,
            BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "new_person";
        }
        getPersonService().addPerson(person);
        return "redirect:/allpersons";
    }

}
```

Initially I am trying to display the form using the URL as `http://localhost:8080/myapp/person`. The code for my form is like this:

**new_person.jsp**

```
<div>
    <h2>New Person Form</h2>

    <sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="person"
        action="person/add">
        <fieldset>
            <table cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="name">Name:</label></th>
                    <td><sf:input path="name" id="name" /></td>
                    <td><sf:errors path="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="age">Age:</label></th>
                    <td><sf:input path="age" id="age" /></td>
                    <td><sf:errors path="age" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="Submit" value="Submit" /></th>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </sf:form>

</div>
```

Now on form submission the URL pattern for my form is `person/add` so the URL is changing to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/person/add`.  Initially I am submitting the form with wrong information so the form is re-loaded with validation error messages.

Now when I re-submit the form with correct values, the URL is going to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/person/person/add` instead of `http://localhost:8080/myapp/person/add`.

Can someone please help me how to fix this basic issue?

Let me know if you need any more details.

Here is my spring configuration file.

adding only main entries of the file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.examples" />

    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

The `PersonService` (has `@Service` annotation) & `Person` are simple classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a single URL pattern for `GET` as well as `POST`.

So in your controller on form submission the handler should be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addPersonFromForm(@Valid Person person,
        BindingResult bindingResult) {
        ... // your code
}
```

In above code I have changed the URL pattern.

Now coming to your JSP, remove the `action` attribute to avoid the URL mismatch.

Making these 2 changes will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see no "form2" reference anywhere. Maybe you missed something at your question? Or just a mistake writing?

Also, as an advice, I suggest you use the same URL using GET and POST methods, as it's a good practice.